# Do $window.location.reload(true) after $state.go

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing this Ionic/Cordova App where I have to do a reload after $state.go. I am doing it like this

```
$state.go('app.menu', {}, {reload: true}).then(function(){
              $window.location.reload(true);
      });
```

The above code works perfectly fine on a browser, the problem appears when I load it onto an iPhone simulator. The problem is it doesn't go to the specified state i.e `app.menu`.

But if I remove the `$window.location.reload(true);`, it does go the state.

What do you think is the problem?

Edit: If I add a timeout it works, ***but I don't want that***. Like so

```
$state.go('app.menu', {}, {reload: false}).then(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
          $window.location.reload(true);
        }, 500);
      })
```

Comment: did you try location.reload(true);

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon I just tried it, the same thing is happening.

Comment: you can try to fix this by setting cache:false like

.state('app.menu', {
            cache:false,
            url: 'you_url_here',

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon should i remove the reload line?

Comment: Yes try to avoid reloading this way, I don't know what is your case here but in single page apps .reload app creates problem

Comment: Could you provide a codepen or plunkr?

Comment: @mhartington [NavCtrl](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyrwEm), it only contains the controller

Answer (score 2):

Use $timout without delay. It works for me.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $window.location.reload(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: [Source Here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/reload-controllers-on-state-change-not-working-in-version-14/17619).

By design, the views are cached.
Try **cache: false** in your state.

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    cache: false,
    url : '/myUrl',
    templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})
```